# What's the difference between listview item and listview footer in rendering life cycle?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-view, android-lifecycle

I have a listview contains items and footer views. Items layout works as it should, but footer's layout doesn't work like item views...

I could't understand where my fault is.  [image]

This is my item's layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/lstCardItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="@drawable/pm_dashboard_cardshadow" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5.33dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="11.67dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="11.67dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivCard"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <com.controls.DynamicResizeImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivCardLock"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:background="@drawable/pm_dashboard_cardmask"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/selector_btn_dashboard_lock" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llInfo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="top|right"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="18dp"
                android:paddingRight="18dp"
                android:visibility="visible" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|right"
                    android:gravity="center|right"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                    android:paddingTop="4dp" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvCardBalance"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvCurrency"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:text="10,344"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:typeface="serif" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvCurrency"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:text="@string/global_currency"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="10dp"
                        android:typeface="sans" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvCardBalanceName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:text="@string/pgDashboard_lblBalanceBanner"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="11.33dp"
                        android:typeface="monospace" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/pm_dashboard_seam" />
</LinearLayout>
```

For my businness side lifecycle:

```
 private void refreshCards() {
    if (applyButtons != null)
        DashboardFragment.this.lvCards.removeFooterView(applyButtons);
    applyButtons = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    applyButtons.setTag("FOOTER");

    applyButtons.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    AbsListView.LayoutParams LLParams = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    applyButtons.setLayoutParams(LLParams);
    if (ininalCount < 32) {
        View createNewCardButton = getApplyButtonView(R.string.pgDashboard_lblCreateIninalCard, R.drawable.pm_dashboard_card_yenikartolustur, R.drawable.pm_dashboard_arrow_icon, new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CreateNewCardActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        View AddCard = getApplyButtonView(R.string.pgDashboard_lblAddCard, R.drawable.pm_dashboard_card_yenikartekle, R.drawable.pm_dashboard_plus_icon, new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddCardActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        applyButtons.addView(createNewCardButton);
        applyButtons.addView(AddCard);
    }

    final View applyIngCard = getApplyButtonView(R.string.pgDashboard_lblApplyToIngCard, R.drawable.pm_dashboard_card_orange, R.drawable.pm_dashboard_arrow_icon, new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CardApplicationActivity.Synchronizer.synchronize((BaseActivity) getActivity(), new OnSyncCompletedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSyncCompleted() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CardApplicationActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    applyButtons.addView(applyIngCard);


    View view = new View(getActivity());
    view.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20, getResources().getDisplayMetrics())));
    view.setBackgroundResource(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
    applyButtons.addView(view);

    bindAdapter();
}

private View getApplyButtonView(int stringId, int backgroundId, int iconId, View.OnClickListener onClickListener) {

    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_list_card_item, null);

    return view;
}

public void bindAdapter() {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        DashboardFragment.this.lvCards.setLayoutTransition(new LayoutTransition());


    DashboardFragment.this.lvCards.addFooterView(applyButtons, null, false);

    if (adapter == null) {
        adapter = new CardListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.dashboard_list_card_item, productModelContainerList);
        controller = new CardListController(lvCards);
        lvCards.setDropListener(this);
        controller.setDragInitMode(CardListController.ON_LONG_PRESS);
        lvCards.setFloatViewManager(controller);
        lvCards.setOnTouchListener(controller);
        lvCards.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        DashboardFragment.this.lvCards.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        DashboardFragment.this.lvCards.setLayoutTransition(null);
    }


}
```

Comment: share your code, so i can guide you properly...

Comment: What exactly isn't working properly? That there is 3 of them ?

Comment: @ArfanMirza I shared my code

Comment: @MahmoudElmorabea My problem is visible card height does not set like items layout. And also, bottom of card layout should align with shadow layout. You can check arrows on screenshot.

Comment: issue is with your relative layout,, you cannot setup align_bottom of view in relative-layout unless you did not set the fix height of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here i made some changes,, use these and let me know... otherwise i need your drawable resources to set this.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/lstCardItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="@color/background_holo_dark" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5.33dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="11.67dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="11.67dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivCard"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivCardLock"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:background="@color/background_holo_light"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@color/bgColor" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llInfo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/cropBG"
                android:gravity="top|right"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="18dp"
                android:paddingRight="18dp"
                android:visibility="visible" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|center_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center|right"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                    android:paddingTop="4dp" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvCardBalance"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvCurrency"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:text="10,344"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:typeface="serif" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvCurrency"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:text="Currency"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="10dp"
                        android:typeface="sans" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvCardBalanceName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:text="pgDashboard_lblBalanceBanner"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="11.33dp"
                        android:typeface="monospace" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/bottom_btn_bg_color" />
</LinearLayout>
```